# awk/sed - searching between lines to return text

Tags: search, sed, awk

i am scanning cisco configs for interfaces that have no descriptions and aren't shut down.

if the interface doesn't have a description, it should be shut down.

if the interface has a description, this is always the first line after the interface. i've written a script that shows me all my interfaces and descriptions using awk, but i am not sure how to do something slightly more complex.

i've run this (if the line following 'interface' *does not* being with 'description').

```
awk '{if ((lastline ~ /^interface/) && ($0 !~ /^ description/)) {print FILENAME ";" lastline ORS FILENAME ";" $0} lastline=$0}'
```

but the problem is, some lines begin with 'interface' and have no config at all, or have something else. so it's picking up the wrong information.

i need something that looks at all lines between each instance of a line beginning with the word 'interface', and if there are no lines beginning with either 'description' or 'shutdown' between, then i need it to print the interface line along with the filename. bit complex for me, i'm a beginner! :(

so for example, this file:

```
interface GigabitEthernet3/23
logging event link-status
shutdown
interface GigabitEthernet3/24
interface Vlan1
description 'VLAN 1'
interface Vlan2
no ip address
interface Vlan4
shutdown
```

will return

```
interface GigabitEthernet3/24
interface Vlan2
```

Answer (score 1):

Some like this

```
awk '!/shutdown|description/ {print FILENAME " - "$1 FS $2}' RS="!" file1.txt
file1.txt - interface GigabitEthernet3/24
file1.txt - interface Vlan2
```

Here I set the Record Selector to `!` and print lines that do not contain `shutdown or description`

---

Updated version

```
awk '!/shutdown|description/ && NF {print FILENAME " - " RS,$1}' RS="interface" file1.txt
file1.txt - interface GigabitEthernet3/24
file1.txt - interface Vlan2
```

This use `interface` as RS.  This may only work with `gnu awk`, since not all `awk` supports multiple characters in RS.

---

Added an `awk` version that do not use RS to be more portable:

```
awk '/^interface/ {if (!f && NR>1) print FILENAME,"-",s;s=$0;f=0} /^shutdown|^description/ {f=1} END { if (!f) print FILENAME,"-",s}' file1.txt
```

And some more readable:

```
awk '
    /^interface/ {
        if (!f && NR>1) 
            print FILENAME,"-",s
        s=$0
        f=0
        }
    /^shutdown|^description/ {
        f=1
        }
    END {
        if (!f) 
            print FILENAME,"-",s
        }
    ' file1.txt
```

Comment: nice one! problem is i realised my actual files don't have ! as a delimiter. they're removed when i pull the configs. edited my output above.

Comment: seems to work ok-ish but not perfectly using 'interface' as the record separator. only thing is it'll miss the last instance of 'interface'...

Comment: also jotne - how do i config it so that the record separators are only the lines that begin with 'interface'? RS="^interface" or RS=/^"interface" don't seem to work.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks a lot Jotne!

Comment: Added an version without `RS`

Comment: i have 200 files which it is searching through, when i apply it with a 'find . type -f' command, it can't make the matches correctly. i think i need to apply it to start anew with each file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^interface/{if (name) print name; name=$0} /^(description|shutdown)/{name=""} END{if (name) print name}' file
interface GigabitEthernet3/24
interface Vlan2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't process line by line. Use "interface" as record separator. The rest of the lines in the interface will be into $0, interface name in $1.